# Having problems with sql edit and insert JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, servlets

I'm using a JSP as a view and a servlet as a controler.
It could be because of the servlet is not receiving the values, idk. I´m a begginer, so please help me.

Code View Editar.jsp

```
<form action="/WebApp05/Controlador" >
            <table class="table table-striped" style="width:autox; text-align:center; margin:50px auto;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Código</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Clave</th>
                        <th scope="col">Estado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="value" value="${datos[0]}" name="codig">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${codig}" name="cod"></td>

                        <td><input type="value" value="${datos[1]}" name="nombre">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${nombre}" name="nom"></td>

                        <td><input type="value" value="${datos[2]}" name="clave">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${clave}" name="cla"></td>

                        <td><input type="value" value="${datos[3]}" name="estado">
                            <input type="hidden" value="${estado}" name="est"></td>
                    </tr>   
                </tbody>      
            </table>
            <div class="botones">
                <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="editar">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Guardar</button>
                <a class="btn" href="/WebApp05/jstl_sql_a.jsp">Cancelar</a>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Servlet Controlador

```
if(accion.equals("editar")){
        String cod = request.getParameter("cod");
        String nom = request.getParameter("nom");
        String cla = request.getParameter("cla");
        String est = request.getParameter("est");

        Connection xcon = this.Conectar();
        sql = "update t_usuarios set cod='"+cod+"', nom='"+nom+"',clave='"+cla+"',est='"+est+"' where cod="+codigo+"";
        PreparedStatement ps = xcon.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("jstl_sql_a.jsp");
    }
```

Comment: Your server don't recieve any data because that input field which you are getting in servlet are in another `form` , instead put all `input` under one `form` tag.

Comment: Also, having a `<form>` element as a directly in a `<tbody>` element is not valid.

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Learn how to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) correctly (i.e. with `?` for values and then using e.g. `setString(...)` method).